# No value accessor while trying to test basic form with angular 4 and ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a simple ionic form:

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Foo</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <form [formGroup]="fooForm">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="name" type="text"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </form>
    <button ion-button full color="primary" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</ion-content>
```

and a page component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'fo-page-foo',
    templateUrl: './foo.html'
})
export class FooPage {
    fooForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fooForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name: ['']
        });

    }

    public save() {
        console.log(this.fooForm.value);
    }
}
```

and a test:

```js
import { FooPage } from './foo';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { Form } from 'ionic-angular';

describe('Foo Page:', () => {

    let comp: FooPage;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooPage>;
    let de: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            declarations: [FooPage],
            providers: [Form],
            imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooPage);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;
        comp.ngOnInit();
    });

    describe('.constructor()', () => {
        it('Should be defined', () => {
            expect(comp).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

project and test structure is based on https://github.com/marcoturi/ionic-boilerplate. The test fails due to error: `No value accessor for form control`.

I was trying various approaches yet it seems that combination of Ionic specifics and recent Angular 4 makes it requiring some additional configuration to be added and some of the existing solutions are no longer valid due to changes in Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this problem two days ago and thanks to isolating it to post on SO was able to get to the solution base on [slightly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113444/how-to-get-set-an-ionic-2-ion-input-formcontrol-value-within-a-formgroup-from-a)

Main point is to add `IonicModule` to `imports` yet this triggers bunch of other Ionic imports:

```js
import {
    App, Platform, Config, Keyboard,
    Form, IonicModule, DomController
} from 'ionic-angular';
import { 
    mockConfig, mockDomController, MockPlatform, mockPlatform 
} from 'ionic-angular/util/mock-providers';
```

and so updated `beforeEach` should start with

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        declarations: [FooPage],
        providers: [
            App,
            Form,
            Keyboard,
            { provide: Platform, useClass: MockPlatform },
            { provide: DomController, useValue: mockDomController(mockPlatform()) },
            { provide: Config, useValue: mockConfig() },
        ],
        imports: [
            FormsModule,
            IonicModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule
        ],
    });
```

PR with the above example got already merged to https://github.com/marcoturi/ionic-boilerplate.